# How to authenticate a wordpress user in external script

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm attempting to check a user's authentication in an external api file. I'm including the wp-load.php file and i'm receiving the following error:

> **Fatal error**:  Call to a member function add_query_var() on a non-object in **/home/USERNAME/public_html/DOMAIN/wp-includes/rewrite.php** on line **1834**

Here's my code:

```
function authentication ($user, $pass){

//Include wordpress files
require_once('/home/USERNAME/public_html/DOMAIN/wp-load.php');


if(empty($user) || empty($pass)){

    return false;

} else {
$auth = mysql_query("SELECT ID, user_login, user_pass FROM PREFIX_users WHERE user_login = '".$user."'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($auth);
$uid = $row['ID'];


$status = false;

$auth = wp_authenticate($uid, $pass );

if( is_wp_error( $auth ) ) {        
    $status = false;
} else {
    $status = true;
}
return $status; 
}
```

}

I removed the username, domain and prefix from this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For anyone else who finds this I simply had to add some global variables as well as passed a string username into wp_authenticate instead of the user id and finally included wp-blog-header.php instead of wp-load.php. Here is my final code:

```
function authentication ($user, $pass){
  global $wp, $wp_rewrite, $wp_the_query, $wp_query;

  if(empty($user) || empty($pass)){
    return false;
  } else {
    require_once('/home/USERNAME/public_html/DOMAIN/wp-blog-header.php');
    $status = false;
    $auth = wp_authenticate($user, $pass );
    if( is_wp_error($auth) ) {      
      $status = false;
    } else {
      $status = true;
    }
    return $status;
  } 
}
```